# Why Jquery outputs string insted of img?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this code , I am trying to output img link ,

but it outputs string : `data/img/admin/ia.jpg agnes:hello`  instead of a picture.

Can anyone help me fix it ?

```
$("#message").keypress(function(e) {
    var test = $("#Uname").val()
    var valmsg = $('#message').val();
    var poza = $('img').attr('src');
    if(e.which == 13 && valmsg.trim() == "" ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please type a message to send');
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#chat").append( "<div class='mesaj' >" + poza + test + ':' + valmsg +   "</div>");
        $('#message').val('');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: you have to create an image tag to set your source. So that it would render into an image.

Comment: What is all this message, chat etc. ? If this is not important to your question, please remove it. What is the HTML context for this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `src` for an img tag and append it to the `div` which you are creating it during the run time.

```
 $("#chat").append( "<div class='mesaj' ><img src="+ poza  +">" + test + ":" + valmsg +   "</div>");
```